# How to do end to end encryption on messages sent by one client to another client with node js and socket io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I build an application on chatting with socketio and nodejs. Now I want to encrypt the messages whenever a message is sent from one client to another client. I need to know the logic and how it can be done end to end encryption.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Do you want to do asymmetric or symmetric encryption?

Comment: ya i know the concepts of asymmetric and symetric but i am not able to implement it as i am new to this node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got it what i was looking for .With "jsencrypt.js"
http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/

calling jasencript as:-
1.  var crypt = new JSEncrypt({default_key_size: 2056});
2.  var privateKey = crypt.getPrivateKey();//To Create Private Key
  var publicKey = crypt.getPublicKey();//To Create Public Key

Comment: But how John and Jane will communicate then? If both private and public keys from John are completely different from Jane?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bcrypt` npm module to do it. Like this:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const message = 'This is my unencrypted message';

bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(message, salt, function(err, hash) {
        let encryptedMessage = hash;
        // your code here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This Medium [blog post](https://medium.com/@weblab_tech/encrypted-client-server-communication-protection-of-privacy-and-integrity-with-aes-and-rsa-in-c7b180fe614e)  could be useful for you to understand.